# IE not recognized aspx.cs codebehind. firefox not getting this issue

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, firefox, code-behind

I have a form and a submission button at the end.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="submission" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-text">Submit form</span>
</button>
```

in my codebehind file I have this

```
protected void submission(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(FirstName.textbox.Text);
}
```

Firefox doesn't give me problems when I execute the page, but IE does. Why?

Comment: What do you expect `Console.Write` to do in a Web Application?

Comment: Why are you using Console.WriteLine?  You're building a webpage, not a console application.

Comment: I also have a custom control and wrote that to make sure that the custom control's fields were accessible

Comment: Replace Console.WriteLine with Response.Write , if you want to see some out put on the page when that event is fired. And what is "FirstName.textbox.Text" ?  Did this code Compile ?

Comment: Microsoft Jscript runtime error: 'submission' is undefined.

Comment: It ran just fine in firefox, IE has the problem

Comment: @jsmith they both fail you just have javascript errors turn on in ie firefox fails silently.  You click event is client side it is referring to "submission" there is no javascript object called submission you have not wired your button to the server side event handler firefox is ju8st posting back because it is a button of type submit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, writing the the console in an asp.net page is nonsense.

Second, your button is client side. As it does not have `runat="server"` it would not fire your server side event that for no apparent reason outputs the value of a textbox to the console.

Answer (score -1):

Try `Response.Write(FirstName.textbox.Text);`
instead of `Console.Write(FirstName.textbox.Text)`